# If $y =\sin \log (x^2+2x+1)$ then $(x+1)^2 y^{(n+2)}+(2n+1)(x+1)y^{(n+1)}+(x^2+4)y^{(n)}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to prove this?

> If $y =\sin \log (x^2+2x+1)$, and $y'=y^{(1)}$, $y''=y^{(2)}$, and so on, prove that $(x+1)^2 y^{(n+2)}+(2n+1)(x+1)y^{(n+1)}+(x^2+4)y^{(n)}=0 $

Finding $y'$ is simple, but $y''$ and other higher terms seems difficult. Any short solution for this approach?

Comment: I think there is some typo.

Comment: it is y(n). Corrected now, thanks!

Comment: Is $log$ the logarithm with base 10 or $e$ here?

Comment: Is $n$ the order of the derivative, so you are writing a relation between the $n$th, $(n+1)$th and $(n+2)$th derivatives?

Comment: Are you sure about the $x^2$ in $(x^2+4)y(n)$?

Comment: It might help to note that $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$, so $y=\sin2\log(x+1)$. Then you'll probably need to use some trig identity, say, the one for $\sin(A+B)$.

Comment: Anyway, why do you have to find $y'$ and $y''$? Then problem says nothing about derivatives.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think he means a relation between the $n$th, $(n+1)$th and $(n+2)$th derivatives $y^{(n)}(x)$, $y^{(n+1)}(x)$, $y^{(n+2)}(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

$y=\sin 2\log(x+1)
=2\sin\log(x+1)\cos\log(x+1)$.

Apply Leibnitz's formula for the n-th derivative of a product and look term-by-term.